# Suggested edit to add status-completed tag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, meta, moderator-tags

I just noticed a very strange [suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16318) on Meta:

> [image: edit]

What is up with this? I thought users couldn't add moderator tags, and, by extension, suggest them. Have I stumbled across a *gasp* bug?

Maybe someone with a sock should try to suggest an edit to add [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) to this question?

Comment: FWIW, no error popped up when I "Approved" it (to check of course, not because I'm a robo-reviwer :P).

Comment: @Matt I doubt the system runs validation checks when users approve or reject edits, so I'm not surprised no error was produced.

Comment: I approved ("for science!") and it stuck.  I wonder if it has to with the fact that Oded had edited it beforehand and he has superdiamond powers.

Comment: (we can roll it back in a minute)

Comment: @jonsca Users can rollback moderator tags? I just flagged it...

Comment: Oops.  Well, so much for forethought on my part.  Now it's time for "Daddddy, we broke your tools, canyuh fixem??"

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn FWIW, One could surmise from [mythz](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168353/mythz)'s use of language that he might be an employee on careers.SE as he is using a lot of personal pronouns.  Doesn't mean this isn't a bug though as you shouldn't be able to suggest this edit, let along approve it.

Comment: @psub All SE employees have diamonds.

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn no, not all, only ones that need it.

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn http://stackexchange.com/users/31281/mythz

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/welcome-valued-associate-demis-bellot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mythz, Demis Bellot](https://stackexchange.com/users/31281/mythz), is one of our [valued associates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/welcome-valued-associate-demis-bellot/) focusing on building our [awesome careers 2.0 site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

As an employee, he can add [tag:status-*] tags, but he is not a moderator on meta, as not all employees necessarily have need for this privilege. He also has <400 reputation, which precludes him from editing questions on the site, which includes retagging.

So that's the reason why the system behaved like this.

Comment: But [he didn't *suggest* an edit here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/131608/revisions).

Comment: Those are months old, the code has possibly changed in the meanwhile. E.g. we removed the retag privilege, etc.

Comment: Retags require 500 rep and suggested edits are years old. Anyway, the current behavior is a bit odd.

Comment: Its high time that @mythz updates his meta about me section, to avoid this kind of confusions..