# How did a user suggest a status tag edit on Meta?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, meta, moderator-tags

Have a look at [this suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17049) which was suggested by [Joshua Hynes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229714/hynes). He suggested [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag. I approved because I can see he is an SE employee. So I have two doubts:

- Why doesn't he have some required privileges? (as he is suggesting instead of direct editing)
- If he doesn't have required privileges, how can a normal user suggest an edit for [status-*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+or+status-bydesign+or+status-declined+or+status-norepro+or+status-deferred+or+status-planned+or+status-review+or+status-reproduced) tags?

Is there any special case here? Just curious to know.

Comment: Yeah, those two edits were confusing. [Dumped a similar thing in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1485893#1485893).

Comment: This happened a week or two ago with another Careers developer. I can't remember the poor guy's name, but he suggested an edit that added a moderator-only tag and you could hear the collective gasp of the community. Not really that big of a deal. Probably just hasn't had any other need for moderator privileges, so he doesn't have a diamond. But he does have the requisite privileges to add these tags.

Comment: @Cody let's hope we won't need to find out what happens if such a poor soul [get banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172344/152859)! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggested edit to add status-completed tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190422/suggested-edit-to-add-status-completed-tag)

Comment: @S.L.Barth: That question is already closed as a duplicate of THIS question. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Joshua is an employee - he's the new designer for Careers 2.0! That gives him certain special abilities, in this case the ability to use restricted tags. It also gives him the ability to edit anything on child meta sites.

...But at the time of writing, MSO was not a child meta site. So he needed approval here.

He now has full moderator rights on MSO, and so will be skipping the suggest-approve dance when status-tagging in the future.

As a note, employees with staff badges [now have full edit privileges regardless of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161/622284), so this won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice he hasn't updated [his website](http://joshuahynes.sqsp.com/about/) yet. He must be *very* new, or you guys must be working him *really* hard. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Haha. Sorry about that. New guy around here. Sorry about some of the broken protocol earlier. And I've updated my website. I have been pretty busy since starting here at SE. We have a lot of great updates, enhancements and features planned for Careers. I honestly just forgot to update my website's About information.