# Careers: no useful response if amazon.com is down

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, amazon

If amazon.com is down (as it is right now), searching for books in the [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/book/reading/[yourid]) returns no results and reports no error. It would be better to show an error message to let the user know what went wrong.

Comment: I'll forward this on to our devs to see what we can do.

Comment: @TheOtherJoel if you're employee for SE where's your diamond? ;)

Comment: @Sha - Maybe we want to add [another request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193545/187824)?? ;)

Comment: I have noticed many Careers employees lacking Moderator bling.

Comment: @hims056 yeah, but until then we can approve his edits. :D

Comment: I should probably ask someone about that.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing I was unable to repro this. Currently we do show an error message if we can't query Amazon's API for whatever reason (which I *was* able to repro), but it can be a bit hard to spot as the error text is plain black at the moment. We'll go ahead and make that error message stand out a bit more.