# I can add moderator only tag via a suggested edit, and I got no diamond!

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, featured-tag

Look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29363) edit. I didn't really expect that I would able to suggest adding [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, but I could!

How is it possible? (seems that usual users can add mod-only tags without moderator help!)

**Edit**

Oded removed [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) back :-(

Comment: suggested edits to add mod only tags was brought up before... I thought it was fixed.  Either it wasn't or it broke again

Comment: Looks like you bypassed the first validation barrier, this is what I get when trying to suggest same edit with a low rep sock: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mM3pA.png :(

Comment: @JanDvorak I think I was confusing 2 posts..  [Suggested edits can remove moderator-only tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230245/suggested-edits-can-remove-moderator-only-tags) was marked as status complete, but dealt with users removing mod only tags.

Comment: ...and [featured] is back. This is definitely broken, good catch @nicael.

Comment: [How can a user suggest a status tag edit on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193545/how-can-a-user-suggest-a-status-tag-edit-on-meta) and [Suggested edit to add status-completed tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190422/suggested-edit-to-add-status-completed-tag) were about adding mod only tags, and both answers only state that "it was an employee, nothing to see here".

Comment: Still, you need a low-rep user and two high-rep users, so it's not that big of an exploit

Comment: Probably related: [*no revision is created when the featured tag is removed from a question after 30 days. ... Thus, when you edit the revision, the tag is still there -- although it does not exist on the current view of the post.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/i-re-added-the-featured-tag-but-it-doesnt-show/92218#92218)

Comment: Why'd you keep deleting and undeleting this post? Just add the [tag:featured] tag! :P

Comment: @Shok deleting and undeleting don't bump it btw. That's just cuz when it needs attention or someone refers to something he saw similar, I'll undelete it. Then, if attention disappears, I delete it (and that's because bounties on it worth me 1050 reps and when I delete, I get those reps back and can spend them on something more interesting :) ).

Comment: Oh, you're devious, @nicael :) ....do I have 500 of those 1050 reps? :P

Comment: @Shokhet I'd say that you have 500 of those 11,850 reps :D (and btw, when I *un*delete, I loose those 1050 reps again, so you can't say that you have 500 of those 1050 reps :))

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that the system tells you not to use that tag, tries to discourage you from using that tag, and you ignore it and use it anyway. Therefore...

#### Solution:

1. Tell folks doing this to knock it off.
2. Take away their editing rights if they don't listen to #1.
3. There is no step #3.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with unborking the system?

Comment: So there should be a step 4...

Comment: Step 3 must always be Profit!!

Comment: @bjb568 The devs have better things to do with their time?  Why spend time and effort fixing problems that aren't actually causing problems?

Comment: @Shog9 - Step 3: Suspend them from retagging or distract them with unicorns and waffles