# Non-moderators can "add" moderator tags with a rollback

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, rollbacks, moderator-tags

I'm not entirely sure whether this is a bug, but it has important implications either way.

Moderator only tags (like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) can only be added by, well, moderators.

However, in the case of [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), the tag is not permanent. A featured tag on a per-site meta or Meta.SE broadcasts the post in the site's community bulletin (or site-wide if coming from Meta.SE), and is removed automatically once the tag is removed by another moderator/employee.

However, as seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/239619/revisions), any user with full editing privileges on the main site or here on Meta.SE can use a rollback to make a post [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) again.

Comment: @nicael I didn't mean to put you under the spotlight, but it's just the post that happened to bring my attention to this.

Comment: And I know why. Because this post is one and only.

Comment: @nicael Interesting, but that's less of a problem, because the only meta with suggested edits is Meta.SE.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I get *"You are not allowed to rollback moderator only tags*" when I try roll back to David's edit of removing the featured tag? I then tried to *edit* David's version of the edit but I get this *"Someone else added a moderator-only tag to this question while you were editing. Please reload the page, but note that your changes will be lost."*

Comment: @lostsock Interesting. I tried it on a Meta.SO post and got the same thing. Maybe you can only *add* them?

Comment: Yes, only me. Really. I'm employee. :)))))))

Comment: Seriously, no user scrpits. You want to know how?

Comment: @nicael I have a feeling that that kind of information should be directly reported to SE.

Comment: @lostsock the exploit let us add featured tag back but not remove it again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard exactly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting; I guess you can only add them. I've updated the question with that assumption.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just tried to add it back on another question by David.. here http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/234453/revisions and it wouldn't let me either way I tried... For just click on rollback got *"You are not allowed to rollback moderator only tags"* and when clicked edit on older revision I get *"An error occurred submitting the edit"*

Comment: @lostsock it's not trivial, but surely possible. Out of time to try it myself, however exact steps to reproduce better be sent directly to the team and not posted here. (nicael don't want to do that for some reason)

Comment: By the way, they are *not* going to fix it. I already spend 1050 repz on bounties on [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234791/i-can-add-moderator-only-tag-via-a-suggested-edit-and-i-got-no-diamond) my report.

Comment: The fact that nicael does not have full editing privileges suggests that there is some old code from when the retag privilege used to exist that is still present in the rollback code. He didn't suggest an edit here, which should have been mandatory even for a tag-only edit. The edit was immediately applied. *That alone* shouldn't even be possible.

Comment: @animuson That's true: I didn't even notice that. I'm still a bit suspicious of this in the first place; it might just be something that nicael's doing.

Comment: I am explaining. I deleted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234791/i-can-add-moderator-only-tag-via-a-suggested-edit-and-i-got-no-diamond) post to get editing privs. Then I accidently added featured tag. After seeing this post, I undeleted mine, because anyway I would look like a cheater. Undeleting this post costed me 1050 repz. Got it?

Comment: @nicael I hope you realize a bounty does not guarantee an instant fix and that Stack Exchange developers don't have magical code unicorns that can automatically fix any problem, no matter how complex the bug may be. (Also, meta rep is just mostly useless imaginary internet points ;) )

Comment: @Doorknob Agreed, but it would be nice for them to at least acknowledge that they're planning on fixing it.

Comment: @AstroCB Sure, we'll look into it, but this is hardly dire so it's not at the top of the priority list right now.

Comment: @Anna so you know how it's being done?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Last time we looked (when nicael reported it), all signs pointed to weirdness with post rollbacks, but we didn't fully chase it down at the time. Other stuff got in the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non-moderators are not allowed to execute a rollback to a version that would re-add a *featured* meta-tag anymore. They get a notice instead like here:

[image: browser alert when trying to rollback before the removal of a feature tag]

[This](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/987/9091) is the question I tested it on.

This is probably related to the fact that expiring [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is now handled by the community user performing an edit.