# Editing a site-meta post with an expired featured tag requires me to restore it

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, per-site-meta, featured-tag

This happened [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/22/revisions). I wanted to add a new tag to and remove another obsolete tag from a question on a site-meta and I could not do so without adding a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, which had been added to the post by a moderator three years ago and was long expired.

It did not matter whether I used the inline tag editor or edited the whole post.

This happened again [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1544/revisions).

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239876/255554) is probably related, but not identical.

Comment: Related: [I can add moderator only tag via a suggested edit, and I got no diamond!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234791/i-can-add-moderator-only-tag-via-an-edit-and-i-got-no-diamond)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expiring [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is now an edit performed by the community user, which fixed this issue. For example [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/987/revisions) an edit did not cause the question to be re-featured.