# I just featured a question on meta...and I'm not a moderator

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-tags, featured-tag

In a strange twist of events, I got this error that said that my edits couldn't be submitted because I needed the moderator tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). I'm not a moderator, so I just decided to humor the system.

And now there's this random old FAQ that's featured on SFF meta as a result ([Where can I ask questions that aren't Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/452/82909)). It's even showing up in the sidebar:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of [the changes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/452/revisions), which don't show me adding the tag, *but I did*:

> [image]

I'm not sure why this happened, but I will note that it's a community wiki [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question and the previous revisions were all done by an ex-moderator whose account is now deleted.

I can't add any moderator-only tags here on MSE though.

Comment: The featured tag was part of the initial revision.  It should have been automatically dropped 30 days later.  The change to CW was two months after the original post, so should have been after the unfeaturing.  *But* I vaguely recall running into a bug c. 2012-13 when I tried to retag a meta post and couldn't because it insisted I add featured, which I couldn't do, and the answer then was that the tag wasn't really *gone*, just *hidden*.  Maybe this information will help someone else figure out what happened.

Comment: As Monica says, until [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266470) the featured tag was magically hidden rather than edited out. This causes [weird](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234791) [effects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92194). This can only affect questions that haven't been retagged since 2016.